# How to make PROJ4 on windows including NZ datum shift grids

Tags: proj

Can anyone point me to an example of how to 'make' proj4 including the New Zealand datum shift grids?

I understand I need to include the shift grids in the build, just not sure how to make it on windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy part is to download the sources and the NewZealand datums.
Ucompres the proj4 distro and uncompress the NewZealand datums in the NAD directory within the proj4.

Then take a look to the INSTALL file. In summary:

- run the 'configure' script to check you have all the required libraries
- execute the 'make' command to compile the sources has specified in the 'makefile' file.
- execute 'make install' command to install the binaries build in the previous step.

I'm assuming you have installed in your system a GCC compiler and so on. If not here is a windows version http://www.mingw.org/